# Angular: how to return HTML validation if email input is null

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I want to be able to create a HTML validation when the input for an email is null. So far it can only return an error if there isn't a correct email input, but not when the input is empty.

```
 get controls() {
    return this.userForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.userForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.userForm == '') {
      return;
    }
    const newEmail: UpdateEmailRequest = {
      emailAddress: this.userForm.value.email,
      confirmEmailAddress: this.userForm.value.confirmEmail,
    };

    this.memberService.updateEmail(newEmail, this.userProfile.id).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.notificationService.success(
          ACCOUNT_MESSAGES.NOTIFICATION.SUCCESS_PROFILE_UPDATED
        );
      },
      () => {
        this.notificationService.error(MESSAGES.NOTIFICATION.FAILURE);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you check with the field this with the status of dirty? something like: ng-touched or ng-dirty